# Using Google Drive API from cloud function using the default service account without generating a key

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-cloud-functions, service-accounts

As far as I know one best practice on Google Cloud is to not use Service Account keys as much as possible.

Here I have a Google Cloud function (nodejs) accessing Drive via Drive API (googleapis package v95.0.0), using a service account key (generated file via console).

**What works:**

```
const settings = require('./config/driveSA.json');
const options = {
         googleKey: settings,
         user: 'test@test.com' //user impersonification
}

const auth = gdriveUtils.prepareJwt(google, options);

const drive = google.drive({ version: 'v3', auth: auth });

const file = await drive.files.get({
    fileId: fileId,
    alt: 'media',
    supportsTeamDrives: true,
});
```

**What I want to achieve:**

I want to improve this function, making it directly use the default service account inherited by the Cloud Function itself (which is the same referred by the key).

This approach always works when using '@google-cloud' related packages. Like for Storage we can simply:

```
const storage = new Storage();
const bucket = storage.bucket(bucketName);
```

**What I tried:**

Without specifying any auth obj:

```
const drive = google.drive({ version: 'v3' });

const file = await drive.files.get({
    fileId: fileId,
    alt: 'media',
    supportsTeamDrives: true,
});
```

Using a not-really-documented method: getApplicationDefault

```
import { GoogleApis, Auth } from 'googleapis';
const adcResponse = await google.auth.getApplicationDefault();
const auth: Auth.GoogleAuth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth(adcResponse);
const drive = google.drive({ version: 'v3', auth: auth });

const file = await drive.files.get({
    fileId: fileId,
    alt: 'media',
    supportsTeamDrives: true,
});
```

Unfortunately the package's [documentation](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/tree/main/samples/drive) is always vague about the authentication part and always use keys in the examples. Is this something viable? Or am I forced to use a key in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: Where should run that piece of code? On google cloud? elsewhere?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere all is inside a Google cloud function

Comment: are you aware that google cloud service accounts are not the same as Google apis service accounts.   Where are you loading the Google apis service account?

Comment: @DaImTo The Google API service account is the same i'm using (driveSA.json in the example). Right now i am able to generate a SA key for it (with domain wide delegation) and use it to do nasty things on Drive.  Question is: why i can't do the same, using the same SA and the same code, but just using the SA INJECTED in my Cloud function instead of generating the key file and feeding the Drive package with it? in the end, is the same service account.

Comment: for starters the there are two different client libraries.   Google apis node.js client (drive)  google Cloud Node client (cloud)  service accounts for cloud client libary are not the same as service account used in Drive.  So if you created a service account for your cloud function its probably not the same one that your using for drive.

Comment: @DaImTo ok if i understood correctly this sounds reasonable and confirms my thought. So In the end i will need to stick to use the Service Account key file, even if it is the same Service Account used by the Cloud Function (or, use a different one). It would be awesome anyway, if one day this could be somehow simplified for code running in a Cloud environment, as we users wouldn't be forced to generate and maintain additional keys. Thank you!

Comment: @OxPenguin did you figure out a way to do this without using a Service Account key file? I am also puzzled by this and it would be really nice if we could get authenticated automatically just like it works with the storage API.

Comment: @AdamD unfortunately not, i came to the conclusion this is not possible so far, and this is a limitation of the libraries and\or Google auth services. This might change in the future..

Comment: @OxPenguin Thanks for the response and yes it's too bad. I can see how it does make sense that things like Storage would be different because it's directly within the GCP ecosystem, whereas things like Google Docs are in a bit of a different pool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As user @DalmTo mentions, you are most likely mixing the accounts. Please keep in mind the fact that there are 2 service accounts involved when using the GCP services and the Google API services:
The GCP service account: Which Cloud Functions is using (most likely the App Engine default [service account](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/iam#administrative_service_accounts)) when you invoke the function.
The Google API service account: Which has the privileges on your drive to perform all sort of actions.

If you would like to be able to perform all those activities in your drive, ensure you are using the Google API service account in your function, this is most easily done through the account key as you mention.